# Canvas overlaid textview brakes image processing

Tags: android

Ok so I have a view:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fancy="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ObjectTrackerActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></FrameLayout>
```

And I am using BoofCV to do some tracking.

```
...
surfaceLayout = findViewById(R.id.camera_frame_layout);
startCamera(surfaceLayout,null);
...
```

I have used existing code from BoofCV repo to get started and get familiar with it.

Now there is an issue when I draw on my canvas TextViews. My onDraw method does something like this:

```
@Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, Matrix imageToView) { 
            drawTree(root,startingXPoint,startingYPoint,viewCenter);
            ...
            ..
}
```

Now the problem is that as I have textViews on top of my canvas I change their background occasionally like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/planElement"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:elevation="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ar_element_background"
    android:padding="4dp">
</TextView>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#0000ff"  />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dip"
        android:color="#1eff00" />
</shape>

...and in Java:
...
..

drawableBackground.setColor(color);
```

So my question is how can I avoid this ? I was thinking of having the textviews added on another canvas that is on top of the one I am looking now, but I dont know how to do that.